# If the Pope were to commit suicide would he go to hell?

Tags: catholicism, papacy, suicide

This question may sound rude but, if someone as holy as the pope were to commit suicide would he go to hell? Considering his devotion to god wouldn't he get some sort of pass? I think someone who gives up on life's desires and focuses on spreading faith shouldn't be sent to hell. And again if this is insulting then I apologize. I used the Pope for my question because I believe that one who holds the    position of Pope would be extremely devoted and most likely the most devoted.

Comment: An hypothetical question can only be answered with an opinion-based response, which is off-topic on this site.

Comment: Suicides are not an automatic ticket to Hell in the Catholic Church. Mental health or any number of issues come into play. This is true even for a pope. God’s mercy extends to all mankind.

Comment: I think the questioner would be satisfied with an answer stating that "The pope would suffer the same fate as any other person in the same circumstances", which I believe to be true but I'm not certain enough to make it an answer.

Comment: Not, I believe, a hypothetical any more than "if a person commits a mortal sin do they go to hell".

Comment: @NigelJ   CCC 2279-2282, and 2325 have some coverage of the topic.

Comment: @NigelJ Short attention span answer is at 2325 *Suicide is seriously contrary to justice, hope, and charity. It is forbidden by the fifth commandment*  CCC 2279-2282 provide a bit more depth.

Answer (score 3):

**The Pope does not get special treatment in spiritual matters such as Heaven, Hell and Judgement.**

In other words, if you ask "Would the Pope go to hell if he did this?" the answer will always be the same as "Would a person go to Hell if he/she did this?", assuming other circumstances are the same.

As Ken Graham points out, suicide does not automatically send one to Hell, so there are other factors to consider. Those factors would be exactly the same as for someone who was not the Pope.

Comment: Would James 3:1 not come into play here?

Comment: @Kris No because they are separate matters.